# Least intensive way of updating cache object from ef list

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, comparison

I'm relatively new to ef and would like to ask for some advice.

I have a standard entity framework with very short lived contexts with a requirement for one page to be updated every couple minutes for each user.

This page relies on data from a table which has 500k+ rows which won't change or be added to very often, so I want this data to be stored in memory rather then pulling the data each refresh....

So what I am looking for is to cache this data in a application level List object but on each request for this information for the cache to be checked and if there are any deltas then only those be queried and updated in the cache rather then pulling the whole table and processing one by one.

So for example.

```
List<T> cache_list; 
public List<T> getdata()
{
     if (cache_list != db.table.ToList())
     {
        cache_list.AddRange(db.table.Except(cache_list).ToList())
     }
  return cache_list;
}
```

I know this will add any new records to the cache but will not update existing rows. Also I think this will be intensive because (and I could be wrong here) either It will have to send the cache to the db or download the whole table before comparing to the other.

Any advice on the best way of doing this?

Edit:
I'm not actually pulling all 500k rows for the page maybe 500 after being filtered but pulling 500 is still more intensive then either no query because the cache is correct or pulling a couple changes especially when lots of users are on he page at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that probably use [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) class and `Onchange` you rebuild your cache. means nullify your older cache and re-load it.

Else consider using a distributed key based caching system like `Redis` and on update of every record :  Check if record exists in cache then update the cache (or) replace the cached object

Comment: Sorry should of said the data In the table can be changed externally from the application so putting in a onchange would only update the cache when an in application change is executed.

Comment: @LRiley, in that case even doing it through EF code also wouldn't suffice

Comment: the context is disposed after each update so unless I'm incorrect the db context should be correct on each refresh yes?

Comment: @LRiley I mean the external update ... even dbcontext is an in app thingy

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, no the cache will be for this application only so i need the application to keep it up to date with as little resource as possible. Yes external apps can make changes to the data but as long as my app cache is correct I don't care about the externals.